# Error in the first line creating mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure in MySQL Community Server 5.5.32 version but I procedure returns an error in the first line but I can not find it. Can anyone help me?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nearestPanel (IN mylat DOUBLE, IN mylon DOUBLE) 
BEGIN
    DECLARE dist DOUBLE DEFAULT 62.14;
    DECLARE lon1 DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE lon2 DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE lat1 DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE lat2 DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE today TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE;

    SET lon1 = mylon-dist/abs(cos(radians(mylat))*69);
    SET lon2 = mylon+dist/abs(cos(radians(mylat))*69);
    SET lat1 = mylat-(dist/69);
    SET lat2 = mylat+(dist/69);

SELECT 
    panels.name, 
    panels.description, 
    cells.*, 
    3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((mylat - panels.latitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS(mylat * pi()/180) * COS(panels.latitude * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((mylon -panels.longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2))) AS distance
FROM 
    cells 
INNER JOIN 
    panels
ON 
    cells.panel_id = panels.id
WHERE 
    panels.longitude BETWEEN lon1 AND lon2 
AND 
    panels.latitude BETWEEN lat1 AND lat2 
AND 
    today BETWEEN panels.date_start AND panels.date_end
HAVING 
    distance < dist 
ORDER BY 
    distance LIMIT 1;
END
```

Comment: [Seems to work with a `//` as delimiter.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8141c5) Try just first typing `delimiter //`, and add your procedure with a `//` after the last line. Then you can give `delimiter ;` to go back to a semicolon delimiter.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean

Comment: Since it's hard to expand in comments, I added more detail in an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Since the procedure contains semicolons, you'll need to temporarily change the delimiter from `;`, for example to `//`;

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE nearestPanel (IN mylat DOUBLE, IN mylon DOUBLE) 
BEGIN
    DECLARE dist DOUBLE DEFAULT 62.14;
    DECLARE lon1 DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;
...
    HAVING 
    distance < dist 
ORDER BY 
    distance LIMIT 1;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with, note the delimiter set to `//` in the dropdown below the code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8141c5/1).

Comment: Ah! Perfect! Sorry for not understanding the previous explanation. Works fine, thanks